# react native t-comb, is there any way to style the error message?

Tags: validation, react-native, tcomb-form-native

I have an input which I want to change (for example) its **fontFamily**.
I couldn't find any solution in the document.
is there any way to change the style of the error message?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, just need to add error attribute to the field:

```
this.options = {
            auto: 'placeholders',
            fields: {
                phone: {
                    placeholder:'شماره تلفن',
                    placeholderTextColor: '#d1d5da',
                    stylesheet: stylesheet,
                    error: <Text style={[styles.font, styles.f13, {textAlign: 'left', color: "#ba2819"}]}>YOUR ERR</Text>
                },

            }
        };
```